# Scheduled Task is Not Showing Up for PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I have a GPO set up to push a scheduled task via computer config. Action is (start a program):

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Arguments:

```
-nologo -noprofile -noninteractive \\DOMAIN\SysVol\DOMAIN\Policies\`{6C8BEF28-CEF8-4608-B59F-59D4356BBC42`}\Machine\Scripts\PSScript.ps1
```

Run as:

```
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
run with highest privileges
```

Also checked box to allow task to run on demand. The task is not showing up on any computer that the GPO is applied to. Any ideas?

Comment: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM can't access the network, can you try to run it as a domain user?

Comment: @Avshalom - Need to run it under the local system account for the script to work. I changed it from BUILTIN\SYSTEM to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM based on the following site (neither builtin or nt authority allowed the task to appear): [http://pratik-pawar.blogspot.com/2013/01/gpo-preferences-scheduled-tasks-not.html](http://pratik-pawar.blogspot.com/2013/01/gpo-preferences-scheduled-tasks-not.html)

Comment: @Avshalom That's not true, you might be thinking of `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService`

Comment: If the task is not showing up, either you policy does not apply correctly, or the task is not setup right. Do you see your policy in "gpresult" on the PC? Run `gpresult /h c:\temp/policy.html` and inspect the HTML file. is your shed task there?